# C++ Define member functions for all template specialized classes

Tags: c++, templates, template-specialization, function-definition

I have a templated class `foo<T>` which is specialized in many different ways. 
Some of which have a lot of common code that relies on specialized functions.

For example, consider the following:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

template <class T>
struct foo;

template <class T>
struct foo<T*> {
    void different_function() const { std::cout << "calling from T*\n"; }
    void same_function() const;
};

template <class T>
struct foo<T&> {
    void different_function() const { std::cout << "calling from T&\n"; }
    void same_function() const;
};

template <class T>
void foo<T>::same_function() const { // this yields an error
    std::cout << "the exact same function but now ";
    different_function();
}

int main() {
    foo<int*> a;
    a.different_function();
    a.same_function();
    foo<int&> b;
    b.different_function();
    b.same_function();
}
```

Each specialization of `foo<T>::different_function()` is uniquely specified, and I want `foo<T>::same_function()` to have generally the same code structure but is reliant on the specialization of `different_function()`.

I have tried:

- adding the methods to the default `foo` type, but that only defines the code *for* the default `foo`.
- using a base class for all the common methods, but that won't work since the `different_function` from the `foo` class is required.

How could I solve this issue?

Comment: second option can actually work, if base class is CRTP. It ony got a problem in relating other declarations, e.g. nested types in `foo`. You need an additional class to handle that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C++23 you can use a templated explicit `this` parameter in `same_function` in the base class:

```
struct CommonBase
{
    // equivalent to:
    // template <typename T> void same_function(this const T &self)
    void same_function(this const auto &self)
    {
        std::cout << "the exact same function but now ";
        self.different_function();
    }
};
```

Pre-C++23 you can use CRTP:

```
template <typename T>
struct CommonBase
{
    void same_function() const
    {
        std::cout << "the exact same function but now ";
        static_cast<const T &>(*this).different_function();
    }
};
```

(Then inherit like this: `struct foo<T*> : CommonBase<foo<T*>>`.)

Or you can avoid specializations in the first place, and just use `if constexpr` and `requires` (or `std::enable_if_t` before C++20) to alter the behavior and to disable certain functions respectively.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! Also, quick note, isn't explicit `this` parameter [C++23](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/function#explicit_object_parameter)?
(also, quick note, how would I implement a cast operator pre C++23 using CRTP?)

Comment: @Mickey Yep, fixed.

Comment: @Mickey What's the difficulty with the cast operator?

Comment: Oh nvm I typed the cast operator wrong (it’s syntax is really weird) thanks anyways!